# Words inherited from other languages

Tags: etymology, roots

What do we call the words which are inherited from other languages (like avatar,yoga etc)? Is there a single word for the class containing these words? As for example, in hindi, some words are directly taken like school, and we call these *"videshaj"* in hindi meaning taken from foreign(*videsh*).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Words borrowed into English from non-English languages are sometimes called [***loanwords***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword)  Examples of such might include *Zeitgeist, façade, jalapeño, sushi*.

However, that “loanword” status is soon dropped as the word spends more time in our mouths, and the origin of the word is no longer considered worth pointing out. For example, we no longer think of words like *canyon* or *tobacco* or *tomato* as coming from “somewhere else”.  After all, every word has to have come from somewhere once upon a time.